# dynamoDB: add to a set inside a map

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

i want to update an item (in java). item may contain map `m`. that map may contain a string set `s`.

i need to add new elements to `m.s` creating `m` and/or `s` if they don't exist. is it possible? can this be done using updateExpression?